# How to query a multi index in RethinkDB over an array of objects

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm working with a data set that looks something like this:

```
"bitrates": [
  {
    "format":  "mp3" ,
    "rate":  "128K"
  } ,
  {
    "format":  "aac" ,
    "rate":  "192K"
  }
] ,
"details": [ ... ] ,
"id": 1 ,
"name":  "For Those About To Rock We Salute You" ,
"price": 1026 ,
"requires_shipping": false ,
"sku":  "ALBUM-1" 
}
```

And I wanted to create a secondary index on `bitrates`, flexing `{multi:true}`. This was my attempt:

```
r.db("music").table("catalog").indexCreate("bitrates", {multi: true})
```

The index built just fine, but when I query it, nothing returns - which seems contrary to every example I've read here:

http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/

The query I wrote is this:

```
r.db("music").table("catalog").getAll(["mp3", "128K"], {index : "bitrates"})
```

There is no error, just 0 results (and I have 300 or so documents with this exact data).

I'm using RethinkDB 2.0 RC1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you create an index for a column, the values in the column are used literally as the keys of the index. In your case, the keys for your `bitrates` index would be the objects within the `bitrates` array in the document.

It seems like what you want is an index that's derived from the values in a field of the document. To do that, you want to define a custom indexing function that reduces the document to just the data you care about. The easiest way to experiment with them is to start by writing a query, and once you're happy with the results, converting it into an `indexCreate()` statement.

Here's a statement that grabs your sample document (with id 1), and plucks the `format` and `rate` terms from all of the objects in its `bitrate` array, and then merges them together to create a distinct set of strings:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').get(1).do(function(row) {
  return row('bitrates').map(function(bitrate) {
    return [bitrate('format'), bitrate('rate')];
  }).reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.setUnion(right);
  })
})
```

Running this statement will return the following:

```
["mp3", "128K", "aac", "192K"]
```

This looks good, so we can use our function to create an index. In this case, since we're expecting the indexing function to return a set of items, we also want to specify `{multi: true}` to ensure we can query by the *items* in the set, not the set itself:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').indexCreate('bitrates', function(row) {
  return row('bitrates').map(function(bitrate) {
    return [bitrate('format'), bitrate('rate')];
  }).reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.setUnion(right);
  })
}, {multi: true})
```

Once created, you can query your index like this:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').getAll('mp3', {index: 'bitrates'})
```

You can also supply multiple query terms, to match rows that match any of the items:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').getAll('mp3', '128K', {index: 'bitrates'})
```

However, if a single document matches more than one term in your query, it will be returned more than once. To fix this, add `distinct()`:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').getAll('mp3', '128K', {index: 'bitrates'}).distinct()
```

If necessary, you might also consider using `downcase()` to normalize the casing of the terms used in the secondary index.

You could also skip all of the indexing business entirely and use a `filter()` query:

```
r.db('music').table('catalog').filter(function(row) {
  return row('bitrates').map(function(bitrates) {
    return [bitrates('format'), bitrates('rate')];
  }).reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.setUnion(right);
  }).contains('mp3');
})
```

That said, if you're almost always querying your table in the same manner, generating a secondary index using a custom function will result in dramatically better performance.

Comment: Thanks Nate - great answer! I think I should have added in my description that my goal was to use a multi index on an array of objects and it sounds like that's not possible with a straight up `{multi:true}`.  This is more of an exploratory thing I'm doing - either way your answer is stellar thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Keys of secondary indexes can't be objects right now:

```
> r.table('foo').indexCreate('bitrates', {multi: true})
> r.table('foo').getAll({format: "mp3", rate: "128K"}, {index: 'bitrates'})
RqlRuntimeError: Secondary keys must be a number, string, bool, pseudotype, or array
```

You can track this issue at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2773 .

For a work-around, you can do this:

```
> r.table('foo').indexCreate('bitrates', function(row){
    return row('bitrates').map(function(bitrate){return bitrate.coerceTo('array');})
  }, {multi: true});
> r.table('foo').getAll(r.expr({format: "mp3", rate: "128K"}).coerceTo('array'), {index: 'bitrates'})
```

Comment: Thanks... user359whatever :). As mentioned I'm using 2.0 RC1, which doesn't do what you're suggesting above - it works just fine without the error.

Comment: Rob -- your post said `r.db("music").table("catalog").getAll(["mp3", "128K"], {index : "bitrates"})` didn't produce an error, does `r.table('foo').getAll({format: "mp3", rate: "128K"}, {index: 'bitrates'})` not produce an error either?